# Couchbase-lite not setup in android with eclipse

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am using this http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-android/cbl-android-1.0b2/#building-your-first-app-with-eclipse to setup couchbase with android android application in eclipse.

But I get following error, How to resolve them?

```
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] The library 'cbl_collator_so-1.0.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] Additionally some of those libraries will interfer with the installation of the application because of their location in lib/
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] lib/ is reserved for NDK libraries.
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] The following libraries were found:
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] - lib/armeabi-v7a/libcom_couchbase_touchdb_RevCollator.so
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] - lib/armeabi-v7a/libcom_couchbase_touchdb_TDCollateJSON.so
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] - lib/armeabi/libcom_couchbase_touchdb_RevCollator.so
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] - lib/armeabi/libcom_couchbase_touchdb_TDCollateJSON.so
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] - lib/mips/libcom_couchbase_touchdb_RevCollator.so
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] - lib/mips/libcom_couchbase_touchdb_TDCollateJSON.so
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] - lib/x86/libcom_couchbase_touchdb_RevCollator.so
[2014-06-14 12:53:41 - groccery] - lib/x86/libcom_couchbase_touchdb_TDCollateJSON.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract  **cbl_collator_so-1.0.0.jar** file and extract files paste in the libs folder.